# How to display all CloudWatch logs from log stream if one log has a specific message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm pretty new to AWS CloudWatch logs query syntax and looking for a solution to my problem.

I want to come up with proper CloudWatch query that would display all the logs from a specific log stream if one log in it contains a unique value.
It looks like executing 1 query based on the result of the previous.

First one looks like:

```
fields @message, @logStream 
| filter @message like /UNIQUE_VALUE/
```

And it yields result in a following form:

```
#  @message      @logStream
1  UNIQUE_VALUE  log_stream/1a23c4
```

And the last query:

```
fields @message
| filter @logStream like "log-stream/1a23c4"
| sort asc
```

Ideally, I want to make it a parameterised CloudWatch query - I input UNIQUE_VALUE and receive an output of **last query**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research on AWS CloudWatch logs, I've discovered that there is not out-of-the-box solution for my problem.
Here is how that is solved if [using SumoLogic](https://help.sumologic.com/01Start-Here/Quick-Start-Tutorials/Hands-on_Labs01%3A_Using_Sumo_Logic/05Lab_5_-_Using_Subqueries_to_filter).

Custom way of solving it on AWS side would be to use AWS API.
Below is possible solution using python boto3 lib:

1. We [create query](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.start_query) to search the logs.
2. We [poll it for results](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_query_results) until we find the value we seek.

It is not what I was seeking for, but it solves my problem, though, with unnecessary complications.

If anyone have other options that I might have missed, I'd be very grateful for sharing your thoughts on the matter.